# I am developing a theme for wordpress, also I am a beginner. As I was coding, the body tag in my css wouldn't work. What can be the possible reason?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

[Coding it in VS code. If you need for info, please let me know.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ2YJ.png)

Comment: Can you please share your code? Html and css

Comment: Thanks for the response man but I just found out the issue. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check via the browser debugging console if any other style is overwriting your css. In chrome, right click with your mouse and select "inspect element" from the popup menu. Find the body tag in the console that should have appeared and click on it. To the right you should see all the css of the element you selected. If you see your own code "striked" with a line it means it's being overwritten by the code above it that looks unstriked.

Comment: Thanks so much, man. You saved my life.  I was coding in some other file so it was overridden with something else. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, if you don't mind to set the answer as correct I'd be very thankful ;)